# Print all root to leaf paths with there relative positions

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-tree

Given a binary tree, how do we print the root to the leaf path, but add “_” to indicate the relative position?

Example:

```
Input : Root of below tree
         A 
       /   \  
      B      C 
     / \    / \
    D   E   F  G

Output : All root to leaf paths
_ _ A
_ B
D

_ A
B
_ E

 A
 _ C
 F

A
_ C
_ _ G
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use preorder travel to visit the tree. Record the path with the indent.

When visit left child decrease the indent, when visit right child increase the indent. Then you are able to get the path like,

```
(0, A), (-1, B), (-2, D)
(0, A), (-1, B), (0, E)
...
```

During the output phase, normalize the path, find the smallest indent for the path node and shift the path nodes to,

```
(2, A), (1, B), (0, D)
(1, A), (0, B), (1, E)
...
```

And then print the path accordingly.

Here's the sample code in python,

```
def travel(node, indent, path):
    if not node:
        print_path(path)
        return
    path.append((indent, node))
    if node.left:
        travel(node.left, indent - 1, path)
    if node.right:
        travel(node.right, indent + 1, path)
    del path[-1]


def print_path(path):
    min_indent = abs(min([x[0] for x in path]))
    for indent, node in path:
        p = []
        for x in xrange(min_indent + indent):
            p.append('_')
        p.append(node.val)
        print ' '.join(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea base on print path in vertical order.

[image]

1) We do Preorder traversal of the given Binary Tree. While traversing the tree, we can recursively calculate horizontal distances or HDs. We initially pass the horizontal distance as 0 for root. For left subtree, we pass the Horizontal Distance as Horizontal distance of root minus 1. For right subtree, we pass the Horizontal Distance as Horizontal Distance of root plus 1. For every HD value, we maintain a list of nodes in a vector (” that will store information of current node horizontal distance and key value of root “).we also maintain the order of node (order in which they appear in path from root to leaf). for maintaining the order.

2) While we reach to leaf node during traverse we print that path with underscore "_"

[image]

```
a) First find the minimum Horizontal distance of the current path.
b) After that we traverse current path
     First Print number of underscore “_” : abs (current_node_HD – minimum-HD)
     Print current node value.
```

Do this process for all root to leaf path.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get Qiang Jin's response to work quite right. Switched a few things around.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val
        self.right = None
        self.left = None


def printTreeRelativePaths(root):
    indent = 0
    path = []
    preOrder(root, indent, path)

def preOrder(node, indent, path):

    path.append((node, indent))

    if not node.left and not node.right:
        processPath(path)

    if node.left:
        preOrder(node.left, indent - 1, path)
    if node.right:
        preOrder(node.right, indent + 1, path)
    del path[-1]

def processPath(path):
    minIndent = 0
    for element in path:
        if element[1] < minIndent:
            minIndent = element[1]
    offset = abs(minIndent)
    for element in path:
        print ('_' * (offset + element[1])) + element[0].value



root = Node('A')
root.left = Node('B')
root.right = Node('C')
root.left.left = Node('D')
root.left.right = Node('E')
root.right.left = Node('F')
root.right.right = Node('G')

printTreeRelativePaths(root)
```